# Need to press the submit button twice on android chrome for form to submit

Tags: android, jquery, html, google-chrome, form-submit

Need to press the submit button twice in android chrome

The first press to the submit button seems to focus the submit button in android chrome. Desktop seems to be working just fine.

Here is a jsfiddle which will show the issue on your mobile phone
[jsfiddle.net/6okhL9yo/1](http://jsfiddle.net/6okhL9yo/1)

```js
$(function() {
    $('#forminschrijven').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
     
        $.post('/rest/data.php?d=contact-contact', $('#forminschrijven').serialize(), function() {
            $('#forminschrijven').addClass('libele');
            $('#resultinschrijven').removeClass('libele');
        })
    });
})
```

```css
.field-label{display:block;margin-bottom:8px;position:relative}.field-label select{border:none;padding:4px 0;border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;width:100%;color:rgba(0,0,0,0.32);display:block;font-size:18px;height:56px;background:#fff}.field-label .field-placeholder{color:rgba(0,0,0,0.32);display:block;font-size:18px;line-height:56px;-webkit-transform-origin:0 0;transform-origin:0 0;-webkit-transition:all .5s;transition:all .5s}.field-label input{-webkit-appearance:none;appearance:none;background:none;border-radius:0;box-shadow:inset 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16);color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);font-family:inherit;font-size:18px;height:100%;left:0;top:0;position:absolute;-webkit-transition:all .5s;transition:all .5s;width:100%;border:none;outline:none}.field-label input:focus{box-shadow:inset 0 -1px 0 0 #1c69e6}.field-label input:focus+.field-placeholder{color:rgba(0,0,0,0.32);font-weight:700;letter-spacing:1px;-webkit-transform:scale(.66) translateY(-26%);transform:scale(.66) translateY(-26%);color:#1c69e6}.field-label input:valid+.field-placeholder{color:rgba(0,0,0,0.32);font-weight:700;letter-spacing:1px;-webkit-transform:scale(.66) translateY(-26%);transform:scale(.66) translateY(-26%)}.textarea-label{padding-bottom:8px;margin-top:16px;display:block;height:100%}.textarea-label textarea{font-family:inherit;font-size:18px;line-height:28px;padding:0;resize:none;width:100%;border:none;outline:none;height:100%;background:#fbfbfb;margin-bottom:0;border-bottom:1px solid #d7d7d7;padding:19px}button,.button{display:inline-block;align-items:center;background-color:#cddc39;border-radius:3px;border:none;color:#fff;font-size:.875rem;font-weight:bold;height:3.3125rem;text-align:center;padding:1rem 1.5625rem;text-transform:uppercase}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="mt" id="forminschrijven" action="/">
           
                    <label class="field-label" for="naam">
                        <input id="naam" name="naam" required="" type="text">
                        <span class="field-placeholder">Jouw naam</span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="field-label" for="email">
                        <input id="email" name="email" required="" type="text">
                        <span class="field-placeholder">E-mail adres</span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="field-label" for="telefoon">
                        <input ngid="telefoon" name="telefoon" required="" type="text">
                        <span class="field-placeholder">Telefoon nummer</span>
                    </label>
                
            <input  type="submit" class="button mtx2 animted fadeIn" value="schrijf je nu in">
        </form>
```

Comment: Hi Nederlander! Could you show us the fbq() function?

Comment: Sry, forgot. fbq is facebook tracking pixel <script>
        !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
            n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
            n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
            t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
                document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'); // Insert your pixel ID here.
fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>

Comment: just confirmed fbq() has no impact, issue remains after removing all facebook code. Edited the question

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle of that, without the FB code, so I can debug in Chrome on my Android phone? The snippet doesn't work in mobile chrome, nor the stack overflow app

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6okhL9yo/1/

Comment: Just tested this https://jsfiddle.net/6okhL9yo/3/ on Android Chrome 58.0.3029.83, the submit button is responsive on the first button press, so I can't reproduce your problem I'm affraid.